# Free or Open Source Database Schema and Data Viewing Software?

Tags: database, database-schema

does anybody know of a tool that will allow for viewing of database schemas and the data within it?  Im using a Mac and need to view a mySQL database.  Basically something like phpmyadmin that runs as more of a stand-alone app and can connect to any mySQL db.

I have found Aqua Data Studio but it is too expensive.

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [Squirrel-SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) (free open source) and [DB Visualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) (has a free closed-source version).

Answer (score 4):

*The* best stand-alone graphical *Windows* mySQL client is [**HeidiSQL**](http://www.heidisql.com/). There is a Java version in the late Alpha stage that runs on OS X and is, if probably not usable yet, definitely worth keeping an eye on: [**jHeidi**](http://www.heidisql.com/jheidi/)

Answer (score 3):

[Database Workbench](http://www.upscene.com) have free lite version

Answer (score 1):

You can give MySQL Workbench ( http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ ) a try ...